# How pass data from ASP.NET Core MVC view and Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

I have a Blazor component and I want to pass data from the view, such as information from ViewBag or a model, to the component I've created.
like this.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    var data = "testData";
}
<component type="typeof(mvcTestBlazor.Components.Counter)" render-mode="Server" data="@data"></component>
```

I expect to send data from the view to the component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this: `param-Data="@data"`

`Page.cshtml`

```
<component type="typeof(mvcTestBlazor.Components.Counter)" 
render-mode="Server" param-Data="@data"></component>
```

In case your `Counter.razor` has `Data` param

```
@code {
    [Parameter] public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This code worked for me, thanks